# How to share a file to be processed between distributed resque workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, resque, amazon-sqs

Imagine that an amazon ec2 instance listens to sqs queue to convert pdfs into images. 
Suppose that we have another 4 instances with 5 works each with resque running and sharing the main redis.

Senario: we recieve a pdf. It has 25 pages ( five pages per server). We upload the file to s3. Then we execute the perform method for each page to generate an image.

My question is: the five instances will have to download the file from s3. Is this recommended? Is there other solutions? Because the 5 instances downloading a 10 mb file to convert separate images seems too slow and expensive...and for each work i have to check the the file system if the file exists...

In overall scability design, this approach is on the right path?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

1. By using s3, you remove the headache of managing your own storage, data transfer bandwidth, relibility/availability, it is good for your overall design in general.
2. I think you should work on the design, make good decision on minimizing redundant data flow/set, define atomic task wisely (not too small nor too big). (for example, can you precut the PDF file into 5 chunks).
3. Also  S3 as file exchange purpose is not that expensive, for ec2 instance within the same region, traffic is  free. pls see aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/